Remarrying on an F1 visa, but my husband has attempted to use F2 and was denied twice
UPDATED. PLEASE READ
I have been separated from my husband for three years. I’m in the US and he’s in Nigeria. He has attempted using the F2 visa but was denied twice. Now I want to remarry . Will it reflect in the US database that I am married because of the 2 attempts or I’m still considered single in the US since he didn’t make it here yet so not officially on the F2 visa ( mind you we bear different names on our passports… I  didn’t take his last name). Will those F2 visa attempts be detrimental if I want to remarry a US citizen? If yes how can I proceed with a divorce or a solution please. Thanks in anticipation
UPDATED PART
He wasn’t told why he was denied the F2 visa twice. We think it has something to do with the name. We both bear different names, we also didn’t do the name publication in the newspaper after marriage (according to the Nigerian law), so probably the marriage isn’t fully recognized in the Nigerian database.. I really can’t tell. The only binding proof of marriage is the Marriage certificate issued by ministry of interiors which is I think recognized fully as a legal marriage. I don’t know if they searched and think the marriage is a hoax due to those reasons. Will they have it documented in the USCIS data base that I have a spouse since he attempted using the certificate but never did get issued the F2 visa? If we are both on the same page and agreed to go separate ways, do I have to go through with the dissolution process or just move on ? Will USCIS be able to trace anything from that singular act of trying for an F2 visa( which included the marriage certificate as part of the document for application)?

Did you marry in the US or in Nigeria/elsewhere? Why was your husband denied an F2 twice? When does your F1 status expire?

Did your husband receive an F-2 visa?  If not, did he apply for one?  If so, why was his application for an F-2 visa refused?

The update is helpful background information but does not change the validity of the answer by @phoog. ’Just moving on’ without resolving whether you were legally married or not in Nigeria is not an option if you want to remarry, and will open up a whole world of trouble if you try. Not a good idea.

@Traveller is right.  I will edit my answer with some more discussion.


I have been separated from my husband for three years. I’m in the US(Ohio)and he’s in Nigeria. He has attempted using the F2 visa but was denied twice. Now I want to remarry . Will it reflect in the US database that I am married because of the 2 attempts or I’m still considered single in the US since he didn’t make it here yet so not officially on the F2 visa ( mind you we bear different names on our passports… I didn’t take his last name.

It doesn't matter what's in the US database.  What matters is whether you are legally married.  If your marriage is legitimate in Nigerian law and has never been dissolved or otherwise ended in Nigerian law then you are not single under US law and cannot marry.  Whether you changed your name is not particularly important.
To establish whether your marriage was valid, and, if so, what steps need to be taken to document the marriage, end the marriage, and document its ending, you probably want to talk to a family lawyer in your state of residence who has some experience with, or is at least familiar with, Nigerian family law.
In response to your edit:
It's entirely possible that the visa was denied not because they thought the marriage was a hoax but because they found that the application had insufficient documentation of the marriage.  In other words, there wasn't enough information.
When you marry in the US, you will have to declare whether you were ever married before and show that any prior marriages have ended one way or another.  If you say that you were never married, the state probably won't challenge that, but when you apply for an immigration benefit on the basis of that marriage, USCIS may find that your second marriage is invalid, or, worse, they might find that your application is deceptive.  If they make that finding, you will be inadmissible to the US, and deportation will likely follow.  This is not a risk you want to run.
The best way to proceed, really, is to have a family lawyer in the state where you will marry, preferably one with experience in Nigerian family law as well, establish that your prior marriage either was invalid or has been dissolved.
Even if you manage to get married and get a green card without doing this, do you really want to spend the rest of your life worrying whether the US will decide that you had used deception?

You're married, whether your husband is with you or not is irrelevant. Bigamy is a felony in Ohio.
For divorce you'll probably need an attorney, especially since you're in different countries.

You’re married is not necessarily correct. If the OP had a Nigerian customary marriage for example, the official registration and documentation necessary for the marriage to be recognised as legal outside Nigeria may not exist.

@Traveller the husband did get an F2 visa somehow. The OP said he was denied using it, not the visa itself. Even applying for it would be admission on the side of the OP that she's married, which ... yes, would be detrimental, especially considering the upcoming marriage to a US citizen which will undoubtedly immediately sponsor the OP for green card.

I disagree. It’s pretty clear in the question that the OP and her husband made two F2 visa applications, but not at all clear that the husband actually got one. ‘Denied’ implies the applications were refused; it could mean he got a visa but was denied entry, however that seems very unlikely. Nevertheless you are correct in saying applying for the visa is an admission by the OP that she’s married.

@Traveller it's more like a claim of being married than an admission.  It seems like there's a possibility that the marriage wasn't valid in Nigerian law, though the very superficial impression I get is that it's more likely that it was valid.  And claiming never to have been married after having claimed to have been married is going to need some explaining if any USCIS officer notices both claims, which does seem rather likely.
